# Debugging layout issues in android studio [widget]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio, and I get a "Problem loading widget" message when I try to create it. Logcat shows this trace:

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:3498)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$AsyncApplyTask.doInBackground(RemoteViews.java:3600)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$AsyncApplyTask.doInBackground(RemoteViews.java:3596)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "48.0dip"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:416)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4818)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:234)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:230)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:226)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:3498) 
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$AsyncApplyTask.doInBackground(RemoteViews.java:3600) 
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$AsyncApplyTask.doInBackground(RemoteViews.java:3596) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is the widget layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="@android:dimen/app_icon_size">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/vertical_line_foreground"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="254dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_default_value"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_default_value"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="297dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/vertical_line_good_foreground"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="145dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="11dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/vertical_line_foreground"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_default_currency"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_default_currency"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="297dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm guessing line #2 refers to the entire layout element. I can't see anything that's to do with "48.0dip", I don't mention this dimension anywhere in my code. How do I debug this sort of issue?

my colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
</resources>
```

my dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="widget_margin">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

my styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you share your project so I'm run in my android studio?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are materials I cannot give away. Do you have any suggestions ass to how I can debug the issue?

Comment: i'm think your problem in files xml ex=> style, dimen, ...

Comment: I added my xml files, except my strings.xml. Do you see an issue?

Comment: change ```android:alpha="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"``` to ```android:alpha="0.5"```

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Comment: if solved, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem in files style.xml

change

```
 android:alpha="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
```

to

```
 android:alpha="0.5"
```

You have to choose from 0.1 to 1